# How to add blob data to Phalcon\Mvc\Model

Tags: php, model, blob, phalcon

I have a class extending Phalcon\Mvc\Model that includes a blob field. I'm currently with Phalcon 1.2.1.

how do i read data? I tried the following

```
ModelClass::findFirst(
  array(
    "name = :name: AND blob = :blob:",
    "bind" => array(
       "name" => $name,"blob" => $base64
    )
  )
)
```

I also don't know how to write the blob. but this process should be equal.

The "work with models" [guide](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html) didn't help me either.

Comment: It seems horribly inefficient to use the full blob data when doing a select.  If you've got a 100K image file, your query is then 100K+ and being passed between your web and database server.

Not to mention, storing binary files in the database is not a great idea to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself by testing. Phalcon seems to work with the same raw datatypes like mysql. For example there are no boolean values. You need to store 0 or 1 for tinyint. The same problem with blob values. You need to pass a binary string like:

```
$hex = "22aabb332299";
ModelClass::findFirst(
  array(
    "name = :name: AND blob = :blob:",
    "bind" => array(
       "name" => $name,"blob" => pack("H*",$hex)
    )
  )
)
```

It might not be the perfect way but worked for me when it comes to this problem.

This way you can store image data or other files directly like

```
ModelClass::findFirst(
  array(
    "name = :name: AND blob = :blob:",
    "bind" => array(
       "name" => $name,"blob" => file_get_contents($path)
    )
  )
)
```